# KMP algorithm for multiple occurrences

Tags: string, algorithm, search, pattern-matching

Is it possible to still perform a O(n) time complexity to search multiple occurrences of Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm?

Comment: For a given K you can run KMP algorithm to find these K different word occurence in O(Kn) =O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a string S[0,...,N]. Recall that the ith entry in the prefix array stores the length of the maximal prefix of S[0,...,i] that matches the suffix. 
We can calculate the prefix array P for pattern$subject (assuming that $ doesn't occur in subject). It remains to find indices such that P[i]==length(pattern), which can be done in linear time.